# Performing a min() search of a multidimensional array Python, then returning a different part of the array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a multidimensional array that contains coordinates and their respective distances (computed via pythagorean theorum).

```
coords = numpy.array([[3,4,5], [5,12,13], [8,15,17]])
```

What I would like to do is perform min() on just the last value of the arrays. In the coords array, I'd be looking for the min of 5, 13, and 17. I'd like to avoid creating another list just to store the last values in each array.

I get that I could just do something along the lines of using a for loop and using the -1 or 2 index, compile all of those, and then run min on that. But my end goal is to return the actual coordinates.

For example, I'd like to build some function closestPoint which takes a 2d array and outputs the first 2 values of the array which contains the closest coordinates. In my case,

```
closestPoint(coords)
```

returns

```
[3,4]
```

Therefore, I think operating within the array itself is the cleanest way of doing this because then I already have the index of the smallest distance.

Sorry if there's an incredibly simple answer (which I feel like there should be)… I'm a beginner programmer and mostly self-taught so there's a lot I don't know :/

Comment: "start there" start where? just read the entire numpy documentation? Do you think that Stack Overflow just forgot to tell me to look through similar posts? Or that every user here is already capable of reading documentations for entire libraries?

Comment: Numpy has a very good introduction guide: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/quickstart.html. You do not need to read all of it or the API, and it's a small time investment for getting to know this powerful library. Your question indicates that you are not aware of some of the fundamental features (array slicing and views - search terms to get you on your way), so this is a good place to start. Nothing wrong with that, we all started at the beginning.

Comment: `coords[coords[:, -1].argmin(), :-1].copy()`

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
print(min(coords, key=lambda i: i[2])[:2])
```

Output:

```
[3 4]
```